# How to show static text correctly on MFC CToolBar using TBSTYLE_FLAT?

Tags: c++, mfc, toolbar

I'm using VS2005 and MFC.  I followed some code online for adding static text to the toolbar. However with the style set to TBSTYLE_FLAT or (TBSTYLE_FLAT | TBSTYLE_TRANSPARENT), the separator becomes visible and looks like a little tick mark above the text.  Is there a better way to show static text on the CToolBar or to make the separator invisible when behind the text?  Thanks!

[image: screenshot]

```
int CMainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
if (CFrameWnd::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
    return -1;

if (!m_wndToolBar.CreateEx(this, TBSTYLE_FLAT | TBSTYLE_TRANSPARENT, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBRS_TOP
    | CBRS_GRIPPER | CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC) ||
    !m_wndToolBar.LoadToolBar(IDR_MAINFRAME))
{
    TRACE0("Failed to create toolbar\n");
    return -1;      // fail to create
}

//Create Static Text
CRect rect;
int nIndex = m_wndToolBar.GetToolBarCtrl().CommandToIndex(ID_STATIC_TEST);
m_wndToolBar.SetButtonInfo(nIndex, ID_STATIC_TEST, TBBS_SEPARATOR, 40);
m_wndToolBar.GetToolBarCtrl().GetItemRect(nIndex, &rect);
rect.top = 5;
rect.right = rect.left + 50;
if(!m_static.Create("Test", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_CENTER, rect, &m_wndToolBar))
{
    TRACE(_T("Failed to create Static Text\n"));
    return FALSE;
}

// TODO: Delete these three lines if you don't want the toolbar to be dockable
m_wndToolBar.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
DockControlBar(&m_wndToolBar);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code you found online is incorrect. It's just adding a static control to the toolbar. The toolbar doesn't know about it or account for its presence.

Answer (score 1):

Probably too late for you, but the TabControl example that comes with MFC shows you how to do it. Basically, you use a class called CToolbarLabel (that is implemented in the sample for you) in the same way you use CMFCToolBarButton and consorts:

```
m_wndToolBar.ReplaceButton(ID_LABEL, CToolbarLabel(ID_LABEL, L"Some label: "));
```

For completeness, here is the implementation of CToolbarLabel:

Header:

```
#pragma once

class CToolbarLabel : public CMFCToolBarButton  
{
    DECLARE_SERIAL(CToolbarLabel)

public:
    CToolbarLabel (UINT nID = 0, LPCTSTR lpszText = NULL);

    virtual void OnDraw (CDC* pDC, const CRect& rect, CMFCToolBarImages* pImages,
                         BOOL bHorz = TRUE, BOOL bCustomizeMode = FALSE,
                         BOOL bHighlight = FALSE,
                         BOOL bDrawBorder = TRUE,
                         BOOL bGrayDisabledButtons = TRUE);
};
```

Implementation file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ToolbarLabel.h"

IMPLEMENT_SERIAL(CToolbarLabel, CMFCToolBarButton, 1)

CToolbarLabel::CToolbarLabel (UINT nID, LPCTSTR lpszText)
{
    if (lpszText != NULL) {     
        m_strText = lpszText;   
    }   

    m_bText = TRUE;
    m_nID = nID;
    m_iImage = -1;
}

void CToolbarLabel::OnDraw (CDC* pDC, const CRect& rect, CMFCToolBarImages* pImages, 
                              BOOL bHorz, BOOL /*bCustomizeMode*/, BOOL /*bHighlight*/, 
                              BOOL /*bDrawBorder*/, BOOL /*bGrayDisabledButtons*/)
{
    UINT nStyle = m_nStyle; 
    m_nStyle &= ~TBBS_DISABLED;

    CMFCToolBarButton::OnDraw (pDC, rect, pImages, bHorz, FALSE,
                                FALSE, FALSE, FALSE);

    m_nStyle = nStyle;
}
```

As you can see it's very light and just uses what the button already provides, so it works for visual themes, too.